# how to check integer overflow for 32 bit signed integer in c

Tags: c

```
int reverseNumber(int x){
long k = x;
long result=0;
int negative=0;
if (k < 0)
{
    negative = 1;
    k = 0 - k;
}
while (k != 0)
{
    result = (result * 10) +( k % 10);
    k /= 10;

}
if (result >INT_MAX)
    return 0;
else
{
    if (negative == 1)
        return (0-(int)result);
    else
        return (int)result;
}
}
```

this is the function code for reversing a 32 bit integer and to check integer overflow condition.The code has to return 0 for the overflow case otherwise the reversed number.For the input 2147483647(INT_MAX) i am still getting the output -1126087180 which actually should be a zero.Please can anyone help with this.
                 thank you

Comment: Maybe you can store result in `int64_t` and use a mask to check for overflow

Comment: thank u.it worked for me now.but what's the problem in using result as long

Comment: Whether `LONG_MAX` is greater than `INT_MAX` is implementation defined (as is whether `INT64_MAX` is greater than either of these).

Comment: @EOF how do you actually check that? Other than sizeof()?

Comment: @sstefan `LONG_MAX > INT_MAX`? `sizeof()` doesn't work anyway, since the types (other than `intN_t`) can have padding-bits.

Comment: @EOF I was thinking like `sizeof(long)`

Comment: @sstefan: And I told you that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version that does **not** mix different integer types. All calculations are kept as `int`. In that way you don't need to care about size of different integer types.

**Note** This part only handles `x>=0`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int reverseNumber(int x){
    int result=0;
    if (x < 0)
    {
        printf("This version requires x >= 0\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (x != 0)
    {
        if (result > INT_MAX/10)  // Check for overflow before multiplying
        {
            return 0; // Will overflow
        }
        result = 10 * result;

        if (result > (INT_MAX - (x % 10)))   // Check for overflow before adding
        {
            return 0; // Will overflow
        }
        result = result + (x % 10);

        x /= 10;
    }

    return result;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", reverseNumber(INT_MAX));
    printf("%d\n", reverseNumber(2147483412));
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
0
2143847412
```